# iPhone Video Screen not rotating

Tags: iphone

I am creating a iPhone application where i play a video.

The problem is view(Video) is not rotating when i rotate the device but in the video palyer, the view is rotating

I am return yes in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method

Can any one provide a solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayer does not rotate, it only appears in landscape mode.  If you attempt to use known private APIs to rotate it your app will get rejected.